# RabbitMQ settings disappear on restart. Why?

Tags: amazon-ec2, rabbitmq

This is on EC2. I have an init script that does some basic setup like installing rabbitmq, creating a virtual host, user, setting permissions, etc. So basically it goes:

```
sudo yum --enablerepo=epel install rabbitmq-server
/etc/init.d/rabbitmq-server start
rabbitmqctl add_user username password
rabbitmqctl add_vhost vhost
rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p vhost username ".*" ".*" ".*"
rabbitmqctl stop
```

Then I exit the shell, and create an EBS image from the instance. Amazon automatically reboots the server to create the image.

Now the weird part...after a reboot everything was still set except the permissions.

Then when I started a new instance from the image, there was no username or host in rabbitmq.

Is there something that needs to be done in rabbitmq to save changes?

Comment: Having an exact same issue. Have you figured this out?

Comment: Disregard that, the issue was that I was using `rabbitmqctl list_permissions` to check them, while I should have used `rabbitmqctl list_permissions -p /vhost`

Answer (score 19):

If the settings disappear when you "stop" and "restart" the instance opposed to rebooting it, it is because the ip address is changing and RabbitMQ settings are bound to the ip.

See [RabbitMQ on Amazon EC2 instances](http://techblog.willshouse.com/2013/02/27/rabbitmq-users-disappear-settings-gone-after-reboot-restart/)

Answer (score 1):

I think it maybe be this, from http://www.rabbitmq.com/ec2.html

> ## Persistent data on EBS device
>
> RabbitMQ writes data to the following directories on Ubuntu:
>
> /var/lib/rabbitmq/ to store persistent data like the messages or queues
>
> /var/log/rabbitmq/ to store logs
>
> If you want to use EBS block device to store RabbitMQ data, just link these directories to your EBS device. Stop RabbitMQ before making any changes to the data directory:
>
> $ /etc/init.d/rabbitmq-server stop

Comment: I am using EBS-backed instances (the root volume is an EBS volume), so those directories are already located on and EBS volume.